# Checking file existence error

Tags: scripting

I am writing script for mining servers. It's taking 2 parameters from https://configmaker.com/my/TintedRawRubberyChafer.txt.
In last you are putting a coin the was mining before now, and on which you want to change.
Script should rename file due to this configuration and reboot the server. So I need to check if file exist. But while checking I got and error. It is only building of algorithm, so don't pay attention. 
Error is

> changer.bash: line 14: [-e: command not found

Here is the script.

```
wget https://configmaker.com/my/TintedRawRubberyChafer.txt
source TintedRawRubberyChafer.txt

file=./btc.stub.conf

if [-e "$file"  ]; then
    rm claymore.stub.conf $last
    rm btc.stub.conf claymore.stub.conf 
fi

rm TintedRawRubberyChafer.txt
```

Comment: use http://www.shellcheck.net/ to catch such syntax errors easily

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message hints, you have to use

```
if [ -e "$file" ];
```

and not

```
if [-e "$file"  ];
```